# Compiler error - covariant return type vs abstract override

Tags: scala

I have a program that in part deals with a type hierarchy. All I'm trying to achieve here is to have the 'oldType' def make use of the covariant return type feature I'm accustomed from Java.

```
trait NumericMember extends  NumericTypedef{ }

trait Type
trait NumericType extends Type

trait Typedef     { def oldType : Type }

class TypedefImpl  extends  Typedef { 
  //can't use a val since it will get overriden
  def oldType : Type = ???
}

trait NumericTypedef extends Typedef with NumericType { 
  abstract override def oldType : NumericType =    super.oldType.asInstanceOf[NumericType] 
}

class NumericTypedefImpl extends TypedefImpl with NumericTypedef{ }

class NumericMemberImpl  extends  NumericMember {
  private val autoType = new NumericTypedefImpl
  override def oldType: NumericType = autoType.oldType
}
```

The compiler blindly tells me that oldType in NumericMemberImpl needs to be an abstract override and then changes its mind when I obey it, figuring out NumericMemberImpl is actually a class.

I might be on a wrong avenue here, since I realize abstract override is used for the stacking traits. When I all I want is to have to have general and specialized return values for oldType.

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've skipped all classess thing here, but the idea is:

```
trait Type
trait NumericType extends Type 

trait Typedef { def oldType : Type }

class NumericMember extends Typedef {
    def oldType: NumericType = new NumericType{}
}
```

The return type is already covariant in both scala and java. You don't need any explicit type-conversion.

About this one:

```
trait NumericTypedef extends Typedef with NumericType { 
  override def oldType : NumericType =    super.oldType.asInstanceOf[NumericType] 
}
```

There is nothing to override, as neither Typedef nor NumericType has concrete implementation of `oldType`. There is also no `super`-class (which is the reason of abstract override recomendation) with implemented method. Abstract override is used to access `super`'s method which is not implemented yet (but will be in the concrete class). You don't need it much as you don't need to call super to get the right type.

To implement some custom type provider:

```
abstract class NumericMember extends Typedef

trait  MyNumericTypeProvider extends Typedef { 
   def oldType = new NumericType{} 
}

trait  MyNumericTypeProvider2 extends Typedef { 
   def oldType = new NumericType{} 
}

scala> new NumericMember with MyNumericTypeProvider
res0: NumericMember with MyNumericTypeProvider = $anon$1@19a26a1

scala> new NumericMember with MyNumericTypeProvider2
res1: NumericMember with MyNumericTypeProvider2 = $anon$1@16bdcbe5

scala> res0.oldType
res2: NumericType = MyNumericTypeProvider$$anon$1@2be1fa9c
```

Look at `res2: NumericType` - scala's type inference automatically found the right type with respect to covariance.

Comment: So I didn't need to override in NumericTypedef . Pretty sure java would have required it hence my initial incorrect approach